# How to set default attribute when set multiple attribute in single state in useState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const [currentTime, setTime] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title:"",
    description:"",
    time:currentTime,
  });
function handleOnclickAdd(){
    setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
}
```

here when I am do console.log(currentTime) show perfect output but when i do  console.log(input) in that show output time:undefine. then How to set time as current time.

Answer (score 0):

when the `input` state is `initializing` the `currentTime` is `undefined` so if you want to change that to another value just change the value to whatever you want like this:

```
  const [currentTime, setTime] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
  });
  function handleOnclickAdd() {
    setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  }
```

Comment: It show default time only , not show updated time

Comment: @PratikVyavahare you need to add the whole component code and the place you're adding `console.log` so I could see what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: @PratikVyavahare Cheers!, if the answer was helpful try to accept the answer and give an upVote to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

because at first stage currentTime is null so you should use useEffect function to handle this :

```
  const [currentTime, setTime] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title:"",
    description:"",
   time:currentTime,
   });
 function handleOnclickAdd(){
    setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
 }
 useEffect(() => {
  setInput(...input , [time] : currentTime);
},[currentTime])
```